# Angular if condition does not read substr condition for ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi im new to angular and js and i was learning ng-show.
I found that if condition in controller was not able to slice or substring the value

My code was

```
 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="row1" size=6/ disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="dup_row1 " size=6/>
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr ng-show="row2()">
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="dup_row1"  size=6/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="dup_row2 " size=6/>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
```

and controller contains

```
$scope.row2=function(){
  if($scope.dup_row1.substr(0,2) > 24){
    return true;
  }
}
```

i only wanted to check first two number to ng-show the next row

Any suggestions are appreciated, also fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/u3yj39u9/

Thanks in advance

Comment: demo link is invalid, please update with correct one

Comment: Thanks i have changed the link....please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code throws immediate error on initial digest that `$scope.dup_row1` is undefined and your function only returns when the intiial condition is met but doesn't return anything if it isn't

A simple fix:

```
$scope.row2=function(){
  if($scope.dup_row1 && $scope.dup_row1.substr(0,2) > 24){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u3yj39u9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Always follow the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models, and you avoid a lot of problems.

so do on your controller:

```
$scope.tableVals = {};
```

And then all of your values should be properties of this object.

[This article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) might be helpful.

Here you have a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/shimonb/HB7LU/16670/)

Comment: hey thanks buddy for your reply...wonderfull..i appreciate your reply